# Prove: If $\ker(A)\cap \mbox{Im}(A)\not = \{0\}$ then $A$ is a singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Prove: If $\ker(A)\cap \mbox{Im}(A)\not = \{0\}$ then $A$ is a singular matrix

Here is my solution. Is it correct?

So my thought was something along the lines of: 
$$\ker(A)\cap \mbox{Im}(A)\not = \{0\}$$
Implies that:
$$\mbox{dim}(\mbox{Ker}(A)) > 0$$
And using this theorem:
$$ \mbox{dim}(\mbox{Ker}(A))+\mbox{dim}(\mbox{Im}(A))=\mbox{dim}(V)=n$$
And because $\mbox{dim}(\mbox{Im}) = \mbox{rank}(A)$ than 
$$\mbox{rank}(A) = \mbox{dim}(V) - \mbox{Im}(Ker(A)) = n -\mbox{dim}(\mbox{Ker}(A)) < n$$
Therefore the matrix A is not of a full rank, threfore it is singular.

Comment: I have grouped together your question and your solution.

Comment: What is your definition of singular?

Comment: If you see $A: V \to V$ as a linear transformation, the hypothesis implies that there is a $v \neq 0, v \in V$ such that $A(v)=0$,  so your inverse should send $0$ back to $v$. Can you do that?

Comment: But already $\ker(A)\ne\{0\}$ implies that $A$ is singulkar ...

Comment: Is it correct that the matrix is not diagonalizeable?